# Reproduce lasso simulation example 1

Tags: r, simulation, lasso-regression

I would like to reproduce the results of example 1 on the page 280 in the original [lasso paper](http://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Etibs/lasso/lasso.pdf).

- The model is `y = X*beta + sigma*epsilon` where `epsilon` is `N(0,1)`
- Simulate 50 data sets consisting of 20/20/200 observations for
  training/validation/test sets.
- `True beta = (3, 1.5, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0)`
- `sigma = 3`
- Pairwise correlation between `x_i` and `x_j` are set to be `corr(i,j) = 0.5^|i-j|`

  I used training, validation, test splitting approach to find the estimates of `test MSE`. I tried to compute a few `test MSE` estimates by hand to check if I'm on the right way before simulation repetitions. But it seems the `test MSE` estimates I find (**between [9, 15]**) are much larger than the ones given by original paper (with median **2.43**). I attach the code that I used to generate the `test MSE`'s.

Any suggestion, please?

```
    library(MASS)
    library(glmnet)
    
    simfun <- function(trainn = 20, validationn = 20, testn = 200, corr =0.5, sigma = 3, beta) { 


      n <- trainn + testn + validationn
      p <- length(beta)
      Covmatrix <- outer(1:p, 1:p, function(x,y){corr^abs(x-y)})
      X <- mvrnorm(n, rep(0,p), Covmatrix) # MASS
      X <- X[sample(n),]
      y <- X%*%beta + rnorm(n,mean = 0,sd=sigma)
      trainx <- X[1:trainn,]
      validationx <- X[(trainn+1):(trainn+validationn),]
      testx <- X[(trainn+validationn+1):n,]
      trainy <- y[1:trainn,]
      validationy <- y[(trainn+1):(trainn+validationn),]
      testy <- y[(trainn+validationn+1):n,]
      list(trainx = trainx, validationx = validationx, testx = testx, 
           trainy = trainy, validationy = validationy, testy = testy)
    }
    
    beta <- c(3,1.5,0,0,2,0,0,0)
    data <- simfun(20,20,200,corr=0.5,sigma=3,beta)
    trainx <- data$trainx
    trainy <- data$trainy
    validationx <- data$validationx
    validationy <- data$validationy
    testx <- data$testx
    testy <- data$testy
    
    
    # training: find betas for all the lambdas
    betas <- coef(glmnet(trainx,trainy,alpha=1))
    
    # validation: compute validation test error for each lambda and find the minimum
    J.val <- colMeans((validationy-cbind(1,validationx)%*%betas)^2)
    beta.opt <- betas[, which.min(J.val)]
    
    # test
    test.mse <- mean((testy-cbind(1,testx)%*%beta.opt)^2)
    test.mse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simulation study, so I think you don't have to use training-validation approach. It just cause variation due to its randomness. You can implement *expected test error* using its definition.

1. Generate several training data sets following your construction
2. Generate an independent test set
3. Fit each model based on each training set
4. Calculate error against the test set
5. Take average

   ```
   set.seed(1)
   simpfun <- function(n_train = 20, n_test = 10, simul = 50, corr = .5, sigma = 3, beta = c(3, 1.5, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0), lam_grid = 10^seq(-3, 5)) {
     require(foreach)
     require(tidyverse)
     # true model
     p <- length(beta)
     Covmatrix <- outer(
       1:p, 1:p,
       function(x, y) {
         corr^abs(x - y)
       }
     )
     X <- foreach(i = 1:simul, .combine = rbind) %do% {
       MASS::mvrnorm(n_train, rep(0, p), Covmatrix)
     }
     eps <- rnorm(n_train, mean = 0, sd = sigma)
     y <- X %*% beta + eps # generate true model
     # generate test set
     test <- MASS::mvrnorm(n_test, rep(0, p), Covmatrix)
     te_y <- test %*% beta + rnorm(n_test, mean = 0, sd = sigma) # test y
     simul_id <- gl(simul, k = n_train, labels = 1:n_train)
     # expected test error
     train <-
       y %>%
       as_tibble() %>%
       mutate(m_id = simul_id) %>%
       group_by(m_id) %>% # for each simulation
       do(yhat = predict(glmnet::cv.glmnet(X, y, alpha = 1, lambda = lam_grid), newx = test, s = "lambda.min")) # choose the smallest lambda
     MSE <- # (y0 - fhat0)^2
       sapply(train$yhat, function(x) {
         mean((x - te_y)^2)
       })
     mean(MSE) # 1/simul * MSE
   }
   simpfun()
   ```

---

Edit: for tuning parameter,

```
    find_lambda <- function(.data, x, y, lambda, x_val, y_val) {
      .data %>%
        do(
          tuning = predict(glmnet::glmnet(x, y, alpha = 1, lambda = lambda), newx = x_val)
        ) %>%
        do( # tuning parameter: validation set
          mse = apply(.$tuning, 2, function(yhat, y) {
            mean((y - yhat)^2)
          }, y = y_val)
        ) %>%
        mutate(mse_min = min(mse)) %>%
        mutate(lam_choose = lambda[mse == mse_min]) # minimize mse
    }
```

Using this function, it is possible to add validation step

```
    simpfun <- function(n_train = 20, n_val = 20, n_test = 10, simul = 50, corr = .5, sigma = 3, beta = c(3, 1.5, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0), lam_grid = 10^seq(10, -1, length.out = 100)) {
    require(foreach)
    require(tidyverse)
    # true model
    p <- length(beta)
    Covmatrix <- outer(
      1:p, 1:p,
      function(x, y) {
        corr^abs(x - y)
      }
    )
    X <- foreach(i = 1:simul, .combine = rbind) %do% {
      MASS::mvrnorm(n_train, rep(0, p), Covmatrix)
    }
    eps <- rnorm(n_train, mean = 0, sd = sigma)
    y <- X %*% beta + eps # generate true model
    # generate validation set
    val <- MASS::mvrnorm(n_val, rep(0, p), Covmatrix)
    val_y <- val %*% beta + rnorm(n_val, mean = 0, sd = sigma) # validation y
    # generate test set
    test <- MASS::mvrnorm(n_test, rep(0, p), Covmatrix)
    te_y <- test %*% beta + rnorm(n_test, mean = 0, sd = sigma) # test y
    simul_id <- gl(simul, k = n_train, labels = 1:n_train)

    Y <-
      y %>%
      as_tibble() %>%
      mutate(m_id = simul_id) %>%
      group_by(m_id) %>% # for each simulation: repeat
      rename(y = V1)

    # Tuning parameter
    Tuning <-
      Y %>%
      find_lambda(x = X, y = y, lambda = lam_grid, x_val = val, y_val = val_y)

    # expected test error
    test_mse <-
      Tuning %>%
      mutate(
        test_err = mean(
          (predict(glmnet::glmnet(X, y, alpha = 1, lambda = lam_choose), newx = test) - te_y)^2
        )
      ) %>%
      select(test_err) %>%
      pull()
    mean(test_mse)
  }
  simpfun()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I need to do the simulation according to the explanations on the page 312 in the [elastic net](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/B67.2%20(2005)%20301-320%20Zou%20&%20Hastie.pdf) paper which uses train/validation/test splitting.

Comment: In that case, I should correct my code to use ‘glmnet’ instead of ‘cv.glmnet’ after creating additional validation set. It might be tuning parameter step and the process can be done similar as test prediction step.

Comment: Thank you for your interest.

Comment: If I set the test set size to 200, the results that your codes give are very similar to my results???

Comment: I thought if the grid is specified well, error will be reduced. I tried several times, but the results was similar to yours. The paper says that it computes *mean squared error*... were they rooted???

Comment: I asked the same question to myself. Some papers use root mse, but in the paper, they don't take root. But following your comment, I reviewed the paper again and I saw they used a different definition of test mse. When I apply that, I see the results are consistent.

Comment: Thank you again. I accept your answer. But, when I click +50, I get a warning "You may award your bounty in 1 hours". I think 1 hour later, it will be ok.

Comment: May I ask one more question? The criteria is `trans(beta_lasso-beta)*covmatrix*(beta_lasso-beta)`. This does not include intercept. But glmnet results include intercept. According to you, should I ignore `beta0` and write `beta_lasso[-1]` in the formulation?

Comment: In fact, I just followed your code the former part. But in case of lasso, it is penalty method. Default option is `standardize = TRUE` because scaling should not affect penalty. If we standardize the data matrix, we do not need intercept term in regression formula.

Comment: In the paper, authors said **8 predictors** and **8 betas**. so I think they did not include intercept term.